# uninstall Net-SNMP?

Tags: homebrew, snmp

I want to install my own Net-SNMP because the preinstalled Net-SNMP is too old. But when I install a newer Net-SNMP via Homebrew, my path doesn't use the latest Net-SNMP.

I would think the best option is to just remove the preinstalled Net-SNMP. How do i uninstall the preinstalled Net-SNMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The best option is to keep the old one, and find out what Homebrew set the --prefix to:

> By default, `make install' will install the package's files in`
>   /usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/man', etc.  You can specify an
>   installation prefix other than`/usr/local' by giving `configure' the
>   option`--prefix=PATH'.

That's the default for Net-SNMP There's a Perl Module involved as well, you may need to set INSTALL5LIB to point to your new installation.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew link --force --overwrite net-snmp
```

This will re-write all the symlinks to point to the net-snmp installed by homebrew.